# Latex expression \int_{a}^{b} x dx in Mathematica - ToExpression+TexForm error

Tags: warning-messages, latex, conversion

I tried to convert a Latex expression to *Mathematica* in this way:

```
ToExpression["\\int_{a}^{b}{x dx}", TeXForm]
```

*Mathematica* gives me an error. How can I get the correct expression in *Mathematica*?

Thank very much for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mathematica is expecting a space between the integrand and the $dx$. So, the following works:

```
ToExpression["\\int_{a}^{b} x \\, dx", TeXForm]
```

> -(a^2/2) + b^2/2

You could see what kind of [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) should work by doing the reverse:

```
ToString[ Unevaluated[Integrate[x, {x, a, b}]], TeXForm ]
```

> "\int_a^b x \, dx"

Comment: Hello @CarlWoll. Is it also possible to get the unevaluated expression? I tried with ToExpression[Unevaluated["\\int_{a}^{b} x \\, dx"], TeXForm], but my statement is blatantly wrong.

Comment: Use 3-arg form of ToExpression, e.g., `ToExpression[texString, TeXForm, Hold]`